# Why is Earth at centre of Celestial Sphere?

Tags: positional-astronomy, celestial-mechanics

Why do we consider Earth to be at the centre for Celestial Sphere ? If so, then how will Sun revolve around Earth ? Doesn't it mean its like the geocentric model ?

Comment: Related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32782/tycho-brahes-model/35055#35055

Comment: A lot of astronomy is still conducted from Earth-based telescopes. A geocentric model is useful for such astronomy.

Comment: Observations are done from Earth. So, the centre of geocentric model should be Earth for better convenience.

Comment: Thanks a lot Guys!!

Comment: Thanks a lot John. Your answer has made me open my eyes and correct my assumption that Copernican model is valid. Thanks a lot friend